# AppleTV 2 HDMI no sound at start sometimes?

Tags: audio, appletv, hdmi

I have an AppleTV2 hooked up to a Vizio LCD TV via HDMI. Nothing between the ATV and TV other than the HDMI cable. I *just* got the ATV2 a week ago and it was updated with the latest iOS update shortly after I got it, so I don't know if this issue is related to it or not.

Sometimes when I wake the ATV and try playing content the video is fine, but the audio is gone.

I have switched HDMI ports and reseated the cables. Still the issue persists.

I've been able to restore sound with mixed success by sleeping/waking the ATV, restarting the ATV, and turning off the TV and turning it back on. Just changing the inputs on the TV to another input and back again doesn't fix it. By mixed success I mean that I haven't found a magic sequence or method that will fix it consistently every time.

The sound does not cut out in the middle of something. It is only "in the beginning", making me think there's something with the HDMI handshake causing it. Once I can get the menu effects sounds while navigating the ATV I know that it'll be okay.

I turned the ATV's Dolby setting from auto to off, but I'm not sure if it has fixed the issue (I don't think I restarted it since doing that and I just changed the setting yesterday after Googling around to see if this will improve sound stability.)

Before I try buying new cables or anything, is there a known issue regarding the latest iOS that has these symptoms? I thought I heard rumor there was another update in the works for the ATV2 but I don't know...I'm kinda hoping I'm not the only one in this boat before I try throwing random money at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First time this happened to me, sleeping and waking worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me yesterday. I simply changed the HDMI port on my TV. For example, my Apple TV was originally in HDMI port 1 and I changed it to HDMI port 2. Seems to have worked fine.

Comment: Tried that...moved from HDMI 1 to HDMI 2.

Comment: I'd give Apple a call. It's not acceptable that we pay for their products and they don't work. Usually, if it's your first phone call, they probably won't charge you and they certainly won't charge you if it's within 90 days of your purchase.